# how can check on records in MySQL db every minute automatically..?

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, database, mysql-workbench

I need some think like trigger in **MySQL** db to check records every minute
 
Example: i have **table 'A'** in my db and i want to change the active Column for the record form 1 to 0 when my current date became greater than end date ... 
How can I do that automatically using **MySQL** db ?

 **DESC 'A'** :

```
name      : string
startDate : DateTime
endDate   : DateTime
active    : bool
```

Comment: what about using jquery ajax ? load that in every 1 minute and check your db

Answer (score 0):

Delete your '**ACTIVE**' field, it is a computed one
and use this sql query :

```
SELECT NAME, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, IF(ENDDATE < CURDATE(), 0, 1) AS ACTIVE FROM A
```

Comment: Thanks but i have product and it has a reserving time , and when the time reserving ended the product returning to view in my web pages by changing the value of active from '1' to 0 .i need some think inside the MySQL db can calculate that and changed the active attribute.

Comment: you want to do a redirection from your web browser when timeout is raised, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Database job and set the interval of one minute.

Comment: Thanks but i have product and it has a reserving time , and when the time reserving ended the product returning to view in my web pages by changing the value of active from '1' to 0;i need some think inside the MySQL db can calculate that and changed the active attribute.